# Rotate an UIImage before upload

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uiimage

I have the following question.

I have made an app where people can upload a picture, but i want the picture to be uploaded the way the picture was made. Now when I make a picture it is uploaded 90 degreed turned. I never said that it has to turn. I tried stuff like:

```
int angle = 0;
switch(image.imageOrientation)
{
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        angle = 0;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        angle = 180;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        angle = 90;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        angle = -90;
        break;
}
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
if (angle == 180)
{
    NSLog(@"180");
    degrees = 180;
    radians = degrees / 57.2958;
    iv.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    iv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
}
else if (angle == 90)
{
    NSLog(@"90");
    degrees = 90;
    radians = degrees / 57.2958;
    iv.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    iv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
}
else if (angle == -90)
{
    NSLog(@"-90");
    degrees = 270;
    radians = degrees / 57.2958;
    iv.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    iv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
}
else if (angle == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"0");
    degrees = 0;
    radians = degrees / 57.2958;
    iv.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    iv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
}
```

but that isnt working. Can someone help me with this?

TLDR; How to check how an image is rotated and rotate it the right way? Or it this something I have to do where the image is showed?

EDIT: Tried to do it in the UIImageView afterwards, but that isn't working

Comment: from where you are taking Image?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use the camera or choose from gallery, both ways its turned. Strange thing is that when I use gallery from the simulator, the image isn't turned...

Comment: When I make the picture in landscape (camerabutton on the right) it is fixed, so somehow it says to my image "Hey man, lets turn you 45 degrees to the right, that would be fun!"

Comment: does it rotate both landscape and portrait pictures?

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin Yes, in every way it rotates the image when I upload it (in the UIImageView is isn't rotated) with -90 degrees. So when I make the picture landscape right (with the homebutton on the right) it has the right orientation and it is saved properly